# c# VssBasicCredential with Username & Password

Tags: c#, web-services, https, tfs, devops

i am trying to create a `TfsTeamProjectCollection()` Object with username & password

this is my attempt:

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(username, password), domain);
VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential(netCred);
```

i use this authentication inside a webservice which is called from an other application
i get no error when i call the web service and use the `TfsTeamProjectCollection` object whatsoever.

if i use an AccessToken created with the user i try to use for authentication it works if i use it like this:

```
VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, accessToken);
```

am i missing something? or is this not possible to do.
also maybe it is importnat that i use https for this webservice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want connect to TFS collection with Username & Password. You can have a try using below `WindowsCredential` object:

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
               
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential winCred = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(netCred);

TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(collectionUrl), winCred);
```

Or you can just use the `NetworkCredential` object:

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
                      
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(collectionUrl), netCred);
```

Comment: this is why i love stackoverflow! fast and high quality answers, works like a charm! Thank you a LOT!